# React Create App and SonarQube Cognitive Complexity

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

For some reason I'm getting critical error from SonarQube as Cognitive Complexity of functions should not be too high (javascript:S3776) on `serviceWorker.js` created by the React Create App.

I know the reason why it got picked up but my question is should I exclude `serviceWorker.js` from the SonarQube scan or add code to the `serviceWorker.js` to skip it for that scanner issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some files in the src folder should be excluded. I use this:
sonar_cpd_exclusions: src/*.js

So, configuration files like .prettierrc.js, .eslintrc.js, and so on doesn't trigger that error